# Event management schema design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing an event management system (to be used for personal events like bdays etc + corporate events + campaign events). The relationships are Event belongs to a Campaign, Events have days and days have sessions. At the same time each of these: (Campaign, Event, Day, Session) can have the same attributes like Budget, Goal, Mission, etc. So should these be stored in their own tables like an event_mission, event_goal, event_budget table or should they be thrown in as columns in the (event, campaing, days, session) tables?

There are other attributes like: Location, Area within a location, People invited, people attending, etc that fit into each of the above, so again I can combine them into their own tables for all like event_loc, campaing_loc, days_loc, session_loc or break them up at each level with one location table and have flags for each level.

Ofcourse this is only applicable for promotional events not personal events.

Comment: I would say the most tables you have, the more expressive and flexible is your database.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that if it's a parameter (like location description, or maximal budget value) it should go inside each table.

If there could be many relationships - like event has many people attending - it should have separate table.

Comment: So if each parameter goes in the parent table then if i need to display a metric to the user: "Show all locations the event has occured in" I have to join these 4 tables to pull all locations?

Comment: I personally would think about each model if it has to have every attribute you specified. For example - why the Campaign should have a location, when there are many events happening and these have location? But to answer your question - if you want to display every location for Event, you just select one table. If you would like to display every Event for a Campaign, then it's one join.

Answer (score 0):

@koressak answer is correct. Basically if a Campaign can have only one budget, then store that budget in the same table as the Campaign... same rule for the others. But think about if you'd need to keep a history of what the budget figure was over time... e.g. if the budget was increased. Do you need to keep a history? If not, then the above is fine; otherwise break it out to a separate table.  If you use a single table to store all those budgets, it will work but your code will be more tricky.